# How to allow only certain users access to a webpage?

Tags: web, bottle

I've made a website and I am using Bottle web framework to display it (I also have other api calls hence I need bottle).

My only problem is that I have a way for a user to register as admin. 
How can I make it so that only an admin can create another admin?

Keep in mind that the project will be open source so even with the source code there can't be a way to become a admin unless an admin allows you to.

My current method is to ask someone to log in and if they are admin show them a register form. 
But if someone checks the source code they could just check the action that form does and get the url of the link which creates a new admin user.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this plugin for bottle http://cork.firelet.net/

I guess this is what you are looking for..

regards